# From Rails to Angular: Are directives used like Rails partials?

Tags: angularjs

I am probably vastly simplifying the use of directives, but to me it seems like `templateUrl` in directives are much like partials in that you load reusable templates with `<directivename></directivename>` much like `<%= render 'partial' %>`.

Here's an example of something I just wrote before coming up with this question:

```
app.directive('filters', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "../templates/product-filters-template.html"
  }
});

app.directive('results', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "../templates/product-results-template.html"
  }
});
```

That feels identical to cutting a piece of ERB into a _partial.html.erb file.

Are directives used in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using directives to render the same markup (same concept as a partial) is one usage, but they can also (and more frequently in my limited experience) be used to control behavior of an element. From the documentation on directives:

> What are Directives?
>   At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element or even transform the DOM element and its children.

For example, you can use a directive to do validation of a user's input into an input element. I would strongly suggest that you read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on directives.